# JSON parse or removing double quotation in data getting form model or database in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts

foo.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var all_user = <%= @user.all_user_bar_chart.to_json.html_safe) %>;
</script>
```

abc.js

```
$(function () {
 if ($("#foo").length > 0){
     var user_charts = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'foo'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User Statistics',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ' ',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'point'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: all_user
    });
    console.log(all_user);
  }
});
```

here the output form model data or foo.html.erb :-
  "[{\"name\":\"A\",\"data\":94},{\"name\":\"b\",\"data\":356},{\"name\":\"c\",\"data\":1}]"

I want to remove the ("") double quotation and supported this data according to `highcharts' to get the basic line chart of user. i also tried JSON.parse but it is not working. every time getting result in string "[{\"name\":\"A\",\"data\":94}]"

Comment: html_safe converting " and \ in to basic text but still output is string ".."

Comment: a quick way to stop bothering with this is to use `gon`

Comment: When I parse json all is fine lie here: 

JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"A\",\"data\":94},{\"name\":\"b\",\"data\":356},{\"name\":\"c\",\"data\":1}]");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving thanks but try to doing without gem.

Answer (score 0):

`to_json` result is string and you need javascript object hash.

In highchart you can set `series` property to object not string, so you need an object from that string, to reach that use this in javascript :

```
series: JSON.parse(all_user)
```

ex:

```
test = "[{\"name\":\"A\",\"data\":94},{\"name\":\"b\",\"data\":356},{\"name\":\"c\",\"data\":1}]"
JSON.parse(test)
# it will return 
[{name: "A", data: 94}, {name: "b", data: 356}, {name: "c", data: 1}]
```

Comment: using to_json.html_safe and JSON.pase(all_user) with different combination getting all series name from hightchart (Series 1, Series 2..........Series 80) but graph is not displaying.